# ruby can't convert Array into String error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do this zip thing 
http://blog.devinterface.com/2010/02/create-zip-files-on-the-fly/

However, I got a bit confussion with returning the path of files using path method that returns the file inside a folder.

```
       def download_zip(image_list)
       . . .
       image_list.each do |img|
       z.put_next_entry(title)
       z.print IO.read(img.path)
       end
```

my confussion is with the z.print IO.read(img.path). Meeans that I need to have a path method in the mode of image_list (isn't it?). I wrote down this path method

```
        def path
        @files = Dir.glob("C:/myfolder/me/*") 
        @files
        end
```

where I have some files inside the "me folder" that I need to return to z.print IO.read(img.path)
but I got an error of can"t convert array into string. Can anyone point out how to do the path method that can return the files and avoiding the array into string problem? I tried to use File.open instead of Dir.glob, and got permission error in windows. 

Thank you for any response

Answer (score 0):

Your `image_list` should be an array of images, each of which implements at least two methods - `path` and `title`. A single image only has a single path - where are you trying to add that path method? It looks like you are trying to add it to `image_list`, which is a wrong place.

Comment: yes, I got lost with adding the method under image_list. If not, where should I add it?

Comment: What are the contents of your `image_list`?

Comment: it contains the id and name only.

Comment: @rahardi: `image_list` should be some kind of container of Images. What do you mean, do you mean that your image_list is an ordinary class with just two attributes, id and name?